# select from one table and insert into another

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got two tables.

> Table_A (nid, vid, type, title, uid)
>
> Table_B (id, questiontext)

I need to insert records from Table_B into Table_A. I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A (nid, vid, type, title, uid)
VALUES ('', '', multichoice', (SELECT questiontext from Table_B), '1')
```

but it's throwing an error.

What should be the correct statement?

UPD: I should add that nid is autoincrement and the value of vid should be same as nid.

Answer (score 58):

Have you tried

```
INSERT INTO Table_A (nid, vid, type, title, uid) 
SELECT  '', 
        '', 
        'multichoice', 
        questiontext ,
        '1'
from    Table_B
```

Have a look at [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: nid is autoincrement. how can I add the newly created nid into vid too in this statement?

Comment: @nrk `NULL`? [character padding]

Answer (score 12):

You should use the following SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO Target(A, B, C)
  SELECT A, B, C
    FROM Source
```

Answer (score 8):

According to the the MySQL [reference for INSERT SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO table_name SELECT FROM other_table [ WHERE ... something ... ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into table2(columnname)select columnname from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

use this method

> INSERT INTO destination (column names )  (select columnaes   from example 3  );
>
> Column should be same type here .

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> INSERT INTO Table_1 (column_1, column_2, column_3)
> SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3
> FROM Table_2
> ```

You can also set some conditions for inserting by as follows:

> ```
> INSERT INTO Table_1 (column_1, column_2, column_3)
> SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3
> FROM Table_2
> WHERE (Condition)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
// if dataset is unique then only we can append data to master table otherwise no data will be appended
// To append unique data you can use this logic
INSERT INTO ut_axis_karvy_master 
(sr_no, funding_ac, funding_nm, micr_no,abc) 
SELECT  
t1.sr_no,
t1.funding_ac,
t1.funding_nm,
t1.micr_no,
t2.id
from    ut_axis_karvy
left join 
ut_axis_karvy_master as t2
on t1.micr_no = t2.micr_no
having t2.id is null;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the correct answer to this might be select into,  from what I see from the other answers is that you guys insert before getting the value from table B as you should first get the value that is : SELECT from table B then insert into table A. you should be searching on the lines of select into

Comment: Here's a quote from MySQL's website: The SELECT ... INTO form of SELECT enables a query result to be written to a file or stored in variables. And this is its [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html). It doesn't help when you want to copy records into another table.