# Moving data from gridview to another table

Tags: triggers

I have two databases sample1 and sample2 both database have same attendance table.

But I retrieve data from sample1 (attendance table) to gridview. I want move data from gridview to sample2 (attendance table) using vb.net.

Is this possible? Please tell me with some links

Sorry for my English

> [select from one table and insert into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377547/select-from-one-table-and-insert-into-another)

Answer (score 1):

The export import mechanism will help if both database on the same server.

Export from the one database using query given below

SELECT * FROM tablename 
INTO OUTFILE '../file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Import into another database using query given below

LOAD DATA INFILE '../file.csv' 
INTO TABLE tablename 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Answer (score 0):

To Insert from one table to another table directly you can use query like this.

> INSERT into TABLENAME1 SELECT * FROM TABLENAME2

Comment: The export import mechanism will help